# Lodash get the removed objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array of objects like:

```
let users = [
     { id: 1, name: 'John Doe'},
     { id: 2, name: 'Robert Doe'},
     { id: 3, name: 'Mary Doe'}
];
```

And these are the IDs that needs to be removed:

```
let ids = [1, 3];

let el = _.remove( users, object => ids.includes(object.id) );
```

Now what I wanted is to get those users data removed. The output that I desire is:

```
[
     { id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}, 
     { id: 3, name: 'Mary Doe'}
]
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Remove returns an array of the removed items. Look at the [example](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove).

Comment: @OriDrori thank you. My bad I was logging the wrong variable -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_.remove()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove):

> Returns
>
> (Array): Returns the new array of removed elements.

```js
let users = [
     { id: 1, name: 'John Doe'},
     { id: 2, name: 'Robert Doe'},
     { id: 3, name: 'Mary Doe'}
];

let ids = [1, 3];
let removed = _.remove(users, (user) => ids.includes(user.id));

console.log('Original users array, without ids [ 1, 3 ]', users);
console.log('Objects with ids [ 1, 3 ]', removed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm very sorry for the trouble I was logging the wrong variable -_-